# Motor driver PWM frequency

Tags: motor, pwm

What can happen to the motor driver if I give input PWM frequency more than the rated(capacity)?

I'm using Maxon motor with specifications:
Operating on 24V 
Speed: 600 RPM
Nominal Torque: 21 Kg-cm

Comment: This is device specific and not normally documented. However if you add the part number of the driver in question, someone may be able to guess based on the type of driver or share their experience.

Comment: If a motor driver has a maximum pwm limit, you may damage the driver, or it may not be able to correctly drive a motor with that pwm.